# Error while using the EndlessAdapter in Android

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

While using [EndlessAdapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless), I came across this error:

Cannot instantiate the type EndlessAdapter at this following statement:

```
EndlessAdapter adapter = new EndlessAdapter(this);
```

I've defined an adapter class in EndlessAdapter.java and have imported it.

This is my entire code:

```
package com.example.litest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.example.utilities.TestListAdapter;
import com.example.utilities.EndlessAdapter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;



public class ListActivity extends Activity{
    public final static String ITEM_TITLE = "title";  
    public final static String ITEM_CAPTION = "caption";  

    public Map<String,?> createItem(String title, String caption) {  
        Map<String,String> item = new HashMap<String,String>();  
        item.put(ITEM_TITLE, title);  
        item.put(ITEM_CAPTION, caption);  
        return item;  
    }  

    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {  
        super.onCreate(icicle);  

        List<Map<String,?>> security = new LinkedList<Map<String,?>>();  
        security.add(createItem("Remember passwords", "Save usernames and passwords for Web sites"));  
        security.add(createItem("Clear passwords", "Save usernames aznd passwords for Web sites"));  
        security.add(createItem("Show security warnings", "Show warning if there is a problem with a site's security"));  
        for(int n=10; n>0; n--)
            security.add(createItem("Clear passwords", "Save usernames and passwords for Web sites"));  

        // create our list and custom adapter  
        EndlessAdapter adapter = new EndlessAdapter(this) 


        //adapter.addSection("Security", new EndlessAdapter(this, security, R.layout.list_complex,new String[] { ITEM_TITLE, ITEM_CAPTION }, new int[] { R.id.list_complex_title, R.id.list_complex_caption }));  

        ListView list = new ListView(this);  
        list.setAdapter(adapter);  
        this.setContentView(list);  

    }  

}
```

Logcat: http://pastebin.com/2WnnJ9KA

Answer (score 3):

> Cannot instantiate the type EndlessAdapter at this following statement:

```
EndlessAdapter adapter = new EndlessAdapter(this);
```

Of course. There is no such constructor. The documentation does not cite such a constructor. The `demo/` app does not use such a constructor. The code to `EndlessAdapter` does not contain such a constructor. Use one of the defined constructors, please. Quoting the documentation:

> `EndlessAdapter` has two constructors. The original one takes a `ListAdapter` as a parameter, representing the existing adapter to be made endless. Your `EndlessAdapter` subclass will need to override this constructor and chain upwards. For example, the `DemoAdapter` inside the demo project takes an `ArrayList<String>` as a constructor parameter and wraps it in a `ListAdapter` to supply to `EndlessAdapter`.
>
> The second constructor takes a `Context` and resource ID along with the `ListAdapter`. These will be used to create the placeholder (see below).

---

> Posted the log cat.

No, you did not.

> I can tell you the problem, that is in manifest.xml I've to add the com.commonsware.cwac.adapter package. The problem here is, my main package is com.litest.main, which is what I've put in manifest.xml

You do not need to have `com.commonsware.cwac.adapter` anywhere in your manifest. Please see the `demo/` project in the GitHub repository.

Answer (score 0):

Post the actual logcat error. In all likelihood, you are trying to instantiate it at a point where "this" does not refer to the proper `Context`. You'll likely need to add the name of your `Activity` class, like `new EndlessAdapter(MyActivity.this);`